# How to combine column value from reapeated rows that differ in one column?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a query that selects number of rows containing repeated rows that all columns values are the same except one column let's call it X column.
What I want to do is to combine all values of X column values in all repeated rows and separate the values with ',' char.
The query I use:

```
SELECT App.ID,App.Name,Grp.ColumnX
FROM (
 SELECT * FROM CustomersGeneralGroups AS CG WHERE CG.GeneralGroups_ID IN(1,2,3,4)
 ) AS GroupsCustomers
LEFT JOIN Appointments AS App ON GroupsCustomers.Customers_ID = App.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Groups AS Grp ON Grp.ID = GroupsCustomers.GeneralGroups_ID
WHERE App.AppointmentDateTimeStart > @startDate AND App.AppointmentDateTimeEnd < @endDate
```

The column which will differ is ColumnX, columns ID and Name will be same but ColumnX will be different.
Ex:
if the query will return rows like these:

```
ID        Name        ColumnX
1         test1         1
1         test1         2
1         test1         3
```

The result I want to be is:

```
ID        Name        ColumnX
1         test1        1,2,3
```

I don't mind if I have to do it with linq not sql.
I used GroupBy in linq but it merges the ColumnX values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this data loaded in objects, you can use LINQ methods to achieve this like so:

```
var groupedRecords =
    items
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.Id, item.Name })
    .Select(grouping => new
        {
            grouping.Key.Id,
            grouping.Key.Name, 
            columnXValues = string.Join(",", grouping.Select(g => g.ColumnX))
        });
```